# Using different passports in Italy

Tags: visas, italy

I am a professional tour director and my work takes me all over the world.  I currently live in the United States but I would like to move to Italy.  It will take some time for me to get an permanent visa but my work would probably ensure that I am not in Italy for more than 90 days in an 180 day period.  It's a lot to juggle though and would mean turning down jobs in Italy so as not to go over my allotted time.  Which would be a shame because I do speak Italian.  However, I do have two passports.  Would I be able to enter Italy on my US passport, hit the 90 day mark, head to France or Switzerland for the weekend and re-enter using my Canadian passport for another 90 days within that same 180 period?

Comment: No, no, no, and no. I'll let others expand on this.

Comment: The entry limits apply per person, not per passport.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is duplicate as well, though I can't find the relevant question. Maybe someone else has better search-mojo than me tonight.

Comment: Do your passports have differing biometrics?

Comment: @Arthur'sPass furthermore, the entry limits apply per the whole Schengen area, not per country in the Schengen area, so going to France is not useful in any way.  Sonja: you'd have to turn down jobs not only in Italy but in the entire Schengen area.

Comment: @Traveller the only biometric data in a US passport is a digitized scan of the photo on the ID page.  I don't know about Canadian passports, but I suspect it's the same.  With matching biographical data, it's quite possible to match the passports even without facial recognition.

Comment: As an experienced tour operator you do know about how the Schengen area works, right?

Comment: @Phoog Interesting, I didn’t know that. My comment was intended as a hint to the OP that her two passports = one person, one rule.

Comment: Sure you can do that!  (Just joking.)

Answer (score 14):

What you are planning to do is break several laws.

As a visitor you are actually not allowed to work in Europe. You are worried that you would have to "turn down jobs in Italy". The reality is that you are not even allowed to accept jobs in Italy.

You intend to take up residence without registering with the local municipality. I know that in the US and other common law countries the municipalities do not keep a population registry, so this may be new to you. In continental Europe when you move to a place you need to register at the local town hall (or whichever local bureaucracy is responsible for this) within a few weeks of your arrival. There they will want to see your long term visa.
If the police find out that someone is living somewhere without being properly registered they may come knocking at our door to check you out. If you are found living there without a residence permit you will get an order to leave the country.

And as others have pointed out to you: The whole Schengen area is basically a single country where it comes to visa and passport control. So you can't just pop over the border to France. There normally isn't even a passport check at the border.

So using two passports to get around this is not really going to work, and will still be breaking the law.

Comment: The registration requirement varies from country to country.

Comment: "The reality is that you are not even allowed to accept jobs in Italy": it's entirely possible that a foreign tour director is allowed to direct tours in Italy as a short-term business visitor.

Comment: That is however not what the OP intends. She wants to live in Italy. That means you would have to pay taxes and social security there, and that would mean taking up a job with an Italian entity.

Comment: "that would mean taking up a job with an Italian entity": not at all.  It would be possible to support oneself with freelance work.

Comment: When I was a freelancer I always worked through an agency. They took care of taxes etc.. The alternative was to found your own company, but I didn't want the hassle. 
in Europe working free lance, while getting all the paperwork in order is a challenge.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to get permission to take up residence in Italy before you actually do so.  Without that permission, you'll only be able to spend half of your time in the entire Schengen area, 90 days out of every 180.  That means that every day you spend in France or Spain or Poland, etc., etc., is a day you can't spend in Italy.

Having two passports might help you get away with violating the law, but it might not, and it certainly doesn't change the application of the law, which is that the restriction applies to you, personally, as a non-EU citizen, regardless of which non-EU passport you present.

Comment: You should make sure that the passport used to enter the Schengen Area (with the entry stamp) should be used while travelling through (and leaving)  the Schengen Area.